# pandas for each date select minimum and maximum time row

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have a dataset like this:

```
id  service         datetime
4   connectsInfo    2016-11-05 06:50:23
4   dayFirstFeed    2016-11-05 06:50:57
4   dayFirstFeed    2016-11-05 06:51:43
4   connectsInfo    2016-11-22 06:42:55
4   dayFirstFeed    2016-11-22 06:42:33
4   connectsInfo    2016-11-22 10:52:11
```

for each date, I want the **min and max time rows**

an approach that I have tried:

```
doc_4.loc[doc_4.groupby(df.request_time.dt.date, as_index=False).request_time.idxmin()]
```

Edit:

I want the result like this:

```
date        min                 max
2016-11-05  2016-11-05 06:50:23 2016-11-05 06:51:43
2016-11-22  2016-11-22 06:42:33 2016-11-22 10:52:11
```

Comment: `doc_4.groupby(df.request_time.dt.date, as_index=False).request_time.agg(['min','max'])`

Comment: @jezrael please check the question again, something is wrong with the code which you gave.

Comment: Sorry, need `df` inside groupby also - `df = df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.date, as_index=False).datetime.agg(['min','max'])`

Comment: thanks, idk why it is marked duplicate.

Comment: Now your code and results are mismatched with your inputs, e.g. what is `request_time`, where did `2016-11-22` data go? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51189456/edit) to make your input & output (real & desired) consistent.

Comment: @jezrael , please post your code as an answer so that i can mark it.

Comment: @jpp sorry for the mess up, i have fixed my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.date, as_index=False).datetime.agg(['min','max'])
```